# PHP, MySQL, Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm getting this error while doing form submit with PHP + MySQL,

```
Error: INSERT INTO artikel VALUES ('aa', 'aa', '2018-06-24')
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

From :

```
<form method="post" name="posting_form" action="submit.php">
Judul Artikel<br>
<input type="text" name="judul_artikel" size="30"><br>
Isi Artikel<br>
<textarea name="isi_artikel" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit artikel">
</form>
$judul = $_POST['judul_artikel'];
$isi = $_POST['isi_artikel'];
$tgl = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "INSERT INTO artikel VALUES ($judul, $isi)";
if ($koneksi->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $koneksi->error;
}
?>
```

What does the error mean?

Comment: Your table `artikel` has more than 3 columns, if you just want to populate some of them then list them as in `insert tableName(col1,col2) values ('a', 'b')`.  If fact I always list the columns as it's safer.

Comment: Also parameterize your query. This is open to SQL injections. The query in the PHP is only inserting 2 values, not 3. Also if those are strings they'd need to be quoted (but using parameterized query would fix that as well).

Comment: change your insert query  "INSERT INTO artikel(col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c')";

Comment: Thanks, guys, it works!